# No-Arg plugin causing lazy delegate to not be initialized and throw a NullPointerException

Tags: kotlin

The Kotlin no-arg compiler plugin is used to create a constructor that has no arguments, even if the class requires them.

This is very useful when dealing with serialization and deserialization, for example reading a value from Amazon's DynamoDB.

The `lazy` delegate is a frequently used feature from the language, however I'm not able to make it work with the no-arg plugin.

```kotlin
@NoArg
data class Foo(val a: String, val b: String) {
    val delegated by lazy { a + b }
}

val foo = getFooViaReflection() // The deserialization that will use the no-arg constructor
```

When accessing `foo.delegated`, it will throw a NullPointerException. Upon further inspection, I discovered that the delegate field is never initialized, and thus it's null when accessed, causing the null pointer.

How to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is somewhat expected, and an issue for that [was opened back in 2016](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16692).

To workaround this, you must configure the no-arg plugin to invoke initializers (the lazy delegate will be created), which is by default set to false.

```
// build.gradle
noArg {
    invokeInitializers = true
}

// build.gradle.kts
configure<NoArgExtension> {
    invokeInitializers = true
}
```