# Kotlin noarg plugin not initializing default values

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, bytecode, kotlin-java-interop

Hello I have the following code(jdk)

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") version "1.7.10"
    application
}

noArg {
    annotation("com.MyAnnotation")
}
```

Classes and annotation

```
annotation class MyAnnotation

@MyAnnotation
class A(
    var a: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
)

@MyAnnotation
class Ab (
    var a: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    var b: String
)
```

When I initialize **A** and **Ab** classes through Java with no args

```
new A() and new Ab()
```

In class **A** field **a** is initialized, but in class **Ab** it is not
Decompiled constructors of A and Ab

```
public A() {
    this(null, 1, null);
}
public Ab() {}
```

But when I use properties instead of constructors

```
@MyAnnotation
class A {
    var a: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}
@MyAnnotation
class Ab {
    var a: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    lateinit var b: String
}
```

Everything works ok and decompiled constructors is

```
public A() {
    Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "randomUUID().toString()");
    this.a = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
public Ab() {
    Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "randomUUID().toString()");
    this.a = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

What I'm doing wrong or it is an issue in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is similar to [No-Arg plugin causing lazy delegate to not be initialized and throw a NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65255929/15028228). Based on the answer there you just need to add one line to your build.gradle.kts:

```
noArg {
    annotation("com.MyAnnotation")
    invokeInitializers = true
}
```

Additional info can be found on Kotlin webpage: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html