# Kotlin NoArg plugin ignores declaration assignment

Tags: kotlin, default-constructor

This problem is related to [Kotlin noarg plugin not initializing default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73071283/14669853).

I've got my NoArg plugin set up like this:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg" version "1.7.10"
}

noArg {
    annotation("tools.AddEmptyConstructor")
}
```

Now, this kotlin code:

```
import tools.AddEmptyConstructor

@AddEmptyConstructor
class Test {

    private constructor(test: String)

    private val declarationAssignment = ArrayList<String>()
}
```

compiles to this java code:

```
import tools.AddEmptyConstructor;

public final class Test {
   private final ArrayList declarationAssignment;

   private Test(String test) {
      this.declarationAssignment = new ArrayList();
   }

   public Test() {
   }
}
```

I get that the empty constructor is supposed to be empty, but why is the declaration assignment, which isn't part of the constructor during compile time, not also being copied into the empty constructor?

How is that intended to be done? I don't have to use declaration assignments and I would be happy with workarounds, but I cannot access the empty constructor and thus not initialize values at all.